# Adjust UILabel font size to fit text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How can i programmatically adjust the font size, to make the text fit inside the `UILabel`, without resize the `UILabel`?

I already have set this:

```
imageCell?.imageText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Also in the Storyboard i have set `Line Breaks: Word Wrap`, `Autoshrink: Minimum Font Size: 1` and `Lines: 0`.

This is how the label looks like:
[image]

This is the whole label text:

> Æ❤️❤️mzbdjdis # Svsuzi. #vdb #%<<,#hs. Clcldbs D. Cmcøclco

But still the whole text is not showing in the label. I am not using AutoLayout in my application. Any suggestions?

Comment: please show an image of your current situation, what you have set to so far should probably work, maybe the constraints of your label are wrong!?

Comment: @luk2302 - Question updated.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to change.

[image]

Setting `Minimum Font Size` will allow the text to resize as the size of the `UILabel` frame diminishes.

So, if you want your text to grow in the `UILabel`, simply set the size of the font itself to be very large, and it will automatically adapt to fit the frame.